# (Roblox scripting) help needed for "GetMaterialColor" or "SetMaterialColor"

Tags: lua, roblox

I am new to roblox scripting, and I am working on a game. I am trying to make an exploration game with multiple planets. I want the colors on the surfaces of the planets to vary, but I also wish to use smooth terrain, as it is easier to use and looks nice. from reading a bit online, i have figured out i need to use "GetMaterialColor" or "SetMaterialColor". however, "SetMaterialColor", the one i needed specifically, requires two bits of information- the material and the color.

The issue comes from the "Material" part of this, as I have no idea how to make the script recognize what material I want to change. i tried multiple things, including but not limited to:
(grass, #,#,#)
(grass) (#,#,#)
("Grass"), (#,#,#)
("Grass", #,#,#)
or even just (#,#,#), without trying to get a specific material at all

so yeah, I need some help

here is the code:

```html
local function onTouch(hit)
    game.Workspace.Terrain:SetMaterialColor

end

script.Parent.Touched:connect(onTouch)
```

(there should be stuff after SetMaterialColor, that is what i need help with)

Comment: I think you should do it like 
`game.Workspace.Terrain:SetMaterialColor(Enum.Material.Grass, Color3.new(0.596078, 0.760784, 0.858824))`
I am totally out of the specific color you need. 
Please checkout this discussion about using the Material https://devforum.roblox.com/t/move-terrain-watercolor-to-terrain-materialcolors/117551 and docs on the Color https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/Color3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation on [Terrain:SetMaterialColor()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Terrain/SetMaterialColor), you'll see that the first argument is a [Material](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/enum/Material) type, which is an Enum. So the method expects an Enum (or number to be more accurate), not a string denoting the material.

At the same time the second argument is a [Color3](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/Color3), so (#,#,#) isn't apt, using it with the constructor `Color3.fromRGB(#,#,#)` is. If you are ever confused about what a method returns or expects, try referring to its documentation on https://developer.roblox.com/.

Here's an example of correct usage:

```lua
workspace.Terrain:SetMaterialColor(Enum.Material.Grass, Color3.fromRGB(123,123,123))
```

---

And ofcourse, Event:Connect() instead of Event:connect()

Comment: While they are both supported, using deprecated methods is a bad habit to get into, not to mention that it violates the consistency of methods being PascalCase, hence the mention.

Comment: Ok, tested it and it worked just fine! the lowercase C in Event:connect() still worked, not sure why. the advice was still good though, and that is what is important!